# Summarise and lm model error

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, lm

When trying to create a table of statistics I am running into an issue with the summary.lm r.squared value.

first, I read in my data from a csv

```
df <- as.data.frame(read.csv("BCO.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
df <- df[,2:4]
```

then I began looking at the trends...

```
CLDD_trend <- ddply(df, .(STATION_NAME), function(z)coef(lm(CLDD_yr ~ year, data = z)))
```

here is where I am running into a problem...

```
CLDD_rsq <- ddply(df, .(STATION_NAME), summarise, rsq = summary(lm(CLDD_yr ~ year))$r.squared)
```

I am getting this error...

```
Error: invalid term in model formula
```

here is the head of df

```
> head(df)
                    STATION_NAME year CLDD_yr
1 ALBUQUERQUE FOOTHILLS NE NM US 1992    3341
2 ALBUQUERQUE FOOTHILLS NE NM US 1993    4443
3 ALBUQUERQUE FOOTHILLS NE NM US 1994    5319
4 ALBUQUERQUE FOOTHILLS NE NM US 1995    5070
5 ALBUQUERQUE FOOTHILLS NE NM US 1996    5338
6 ALBUQUERQUE FOOTHILLS NE NM US 1997    5105
```

and the head of CLDD_trend

```
> head(CLDD_trend)
                             STATION_NAME (Intercept)      year
1          ALBUQUERQUE FOOTHILLS NE NM US -185183.485 95.159091
2 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US -138428.871 73.121774
3                   ALBUQUERQUE VLY NM US -138218.809 72.243478
4           PETROGLYPH NATIONAL MON NM US  -95959.130 51.074086
5                       SANDIA PARK NM US    7758.845 -3.439124
```

my aim is to append a new column to CLDD_trend that contains the results of the r.squared portion of the summarise function.

```
stat <- cbind(CLDD_trend[,1&3], CLDD_rsq$rsq)
```

Can you see where the error in my model is? I am stumped.

Comment: I think it is because you don't supply the data to the lm. You could get both the coef and the rsq from the same ddply run if you wanted to. Also read.csv returns a data.frame so you don't need to run as.data.frame

Comment: The data is supplied to lm the same way as it is in the previous line.. perhaps I am confused about what you mean. eitherway, would you provide an example of how to combine the ddply runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had some sort of conflict with dplyr and plyr.

I solved the issue by

```
detach()
library(plyr)
df <- as.data.frame(read.csv("BCO.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
df <- df[,2:4]
CLDD_trend <- ddply(df, .(STATION_NAME), function(z)coef(lm(CLDD_yr ~ year, data = z)))
CLDD_rsq <- ddply(df, .(STATION_NAME), summarise, rsq = summary(lm(CLDD_yr ~ year))$r.squared)
stat <- cbind(CLDD_trend[,1&3], CLDD_rsq$rsq)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to extract the two statistics with a single run

```
CLDD_trend <- ddply(df, .(STATION_NAME), function(z){
  mod <- lm(CLDD_yr ~ year, data = z)
  c(coef(mod), rsq = summary(mod)$r.squared
})
```